# tensorflow c++ error: Unary VariantShapeFn for type_name: int already registered

Tags: c++11, tensorflow

i compliled tensorflow with bazel successfully and got libtensorflow_cc.so and libtensorflow_framework.so. Then i built a c++ binary with those share libraries successfully, but errors occurred when i run the binary, info is like:

```
F tensorflow/core/framework/variant_op_registry.cc:51] Check failed: existing == nullptr (0x24fc538 vs. nullptr)Unary VariantShapeFn for type_name: int already registered
```

c++ code:

```
#include "tensorflow/cc/client/client_session.h"
#include "tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h"
#include "tensorflow/core/framework/tensor.h"
int main() {
    using namespace tensorflow;
    using namespace tensorflow::ops;
    Scope root = Scope::NewRootScope();auto A = Const(root, { {3.f, 2.f}, {-1.f, 0.f}  });
    //     // Vector b = [3 5
    auto b = Const(root, { {3.f, 5.f}  });
    auto v = MatMul(root.WithOpName("v"), A, b, MatMul::TransposeB(true));
    std::vector<Tensor> outputs;
    ClientSession session(root);
    // Run and fetch v
    TF_CHECK_OK(session.Run({v}, &outputs));
    // Expect outputs[0] == [19; -3]
    LOG(INFO) << outputs[0].matrix<float>();
    return 0;
}
```

i got my c++ binary using cmd:

```
g++ -std=c++11 test.cpp -o test -I./include -L./lib -L/home/work/chengjy/tools/protobuf/lib -I/home/work/chengjy/tools/tensorflow/eigen/eigen/eigen-eigen-fd6845384b86 -I/home/work/chengjy/tools/protobuf/include -ltensorflow_cc -ltensorflow_framework  -lprotobuf -lpthread -ldl -O3 -Wall
```

did anyone have this problem before?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that i fixed this problem by removing -ltensorflow_framework from the compile cmd.